# Writing a polling Windows service

Tags: f#, windows-services, backgroundworker

I usually write Windows services in C# but I'm giving it a go in F#. For a polling serivce, like this one, I ordinarily use a class I've written, which is similar to [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). It spawns a background thread and fires an *OnWork* method at regular intervals. (Complete code is [here <sup>[github]</sup>](https://gist.github.com/1235595).)

Is there another, perhaps better or more idiomatic, way to do this in F#? It could be a better way to write the polling background worker class, or built-in alternatives to it.

#### EDIT

Here's what I came up, based on Joel's suggestion.

```
module Async =
  open System.Diagnostics

  let poll interval work =
    let sw = Stopwatch()
    let rec loop() =
      async {
        sw.Restart()
        work()
        sw.Stop()
        let elapsed = int sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
        if elapsed < interval then
          do! Async.Sleep(interval - elapsed)
        return! loop()
      }
    loop()

//Example
open System.Threading
let cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
Async.Start(Async.poll 2000 (fun () -> printfn "%A" DateTime.Now), cts.Token)
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
cts.Cancel()
```

The service using `poll`:

```
type MyService() =
  inherit System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase()

  let mutable cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
  let interval = 2000

  override __.OnStart(_) = 
    let polling = Async.poll interval (fun () ->
      //do work
    )
    Async.Start(polling, cts.Token)

  override __.OnStop() = 
    cts.Cancel()
    cts.Dispose()
    cts <- new CancellationTokenSource()

  override __.Dispose(disposing) =
    if disposing then cts.Dispose()
    base.Dispose(true)
```

I wish there was a way to avoid the mutable `CancellationTokenSource`, but alas.

Comment: On a related note someone created a F# service template.  It might contain some good boiler plate code however it doesn't contain anything about polling. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1f2ee1da-e87f-4863-b98e-d8b7b63d2253?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: I saw that. Thanks. I wish I knew how to publish some proposed improvements to it.

Comment: +1 for updating your question with your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be tempted to write a simple loop in an asynchronous workflow. You can use `do! Async.Sleep interval` to sleep in between polling - this has two advantages: you're not tying up a thread just to have it sit idle with `Thread.Sleep`, and the `do!` automatically checks for cancellation for you if you pass a `CancellationToken` into `Async.Start`.

Plus, if your polling operation involves network communication, you're already in an async workflow, making it trivial to make async network calls.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines but wasn't sure how to send start/stop signals (it needs to be restartable). Would `MailboxProcessor` yield a good solution?

Comment: Well, if your loop is in an async workflow, you can create a `CancellationTokenSource` and start the workflow with `Async.Start(myLoop, cts.Token)`. To stop, call `cts.Cancel()`. To restart, start the workflow again the same way you did the first time...

Comment: Joel's advice may work well; alternatively you might explicitly (or implicitly via control flow) represent the state machine inside a MailboxProcessor.  If you want to emphasize the states and transitions, then I think I would use a MailboxProcessor and explicit states; if you want to emphasize the work, and have the states/transitions just be part of the necessity of the service, I might just use an async loop with `Start`/`Cancel`.  But I am guessing, not based on experience in this domain.

Comment: I updated my question with my solution, based on your answer. Seems to work great. Many thanks.

Comment: @Brian: I was leaning toward `MailboxProcessor`, but I think in this case the only transitions I care about are stopping/starting, which is handled nicely by `async`+`CancellationToken`.

Comment: @Joel: I don't have much experience with `CancellationTokenSource`. Do you spot any problems in the service code?

Comment: @Daniel - That's pretty much exactly the sort of thing I had in mind. Looks good to me. Depending on what I was actually trying to accomplish, I might make `work` an `Async<unit>` instead of a `unit -> unit` but that's pretty situational.