# F# Email Listener

Tags: .net, service, f#, listener, imap

I would like to make an email listener that listens to an imap mailbox.  My basic idea is just to keep polling the server using an imap client, how would I create this sort of loop in f# and how could I turn the program into a service that can be started and stopped cleanly.  Also, is there any better way to listen to an imap server than polling it every few seconds?

**EDIT**:

I found this question which answers my questions about creating a service:
[Writing a polling Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519755/writing-a-polling-windows-service).
However the question still remains, is this the correct way to go about listening to an IMAP mailbox.  Will there be any likely problems?

**EDIT 2**

I have been looking at S22.Imap which uses an event handler in C# however I'm not sure how to implement this in F#, basically this line:

```
// We want to be informed when new messages arrive
Client.NewMessage += new EventHandler<IdleMessageEventArgs>(OnNewMessage);
```

I presume this is how the program is kept alive, does it sit on this line waiting for events?

The author of the code has also put this underneath which I don't quite understand:

```
// Put calling thread to sleep. This is just so the example program does
// not immediately exit.
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
```

Could someone explain to me how I can go about implementing this in F#?  The full example is available [here](https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap/blob/master/Examples.md).

**Edit 3**

Not sure exactly why this question was closed, perhaps the last sentence of Edit 2 was not read.  So my question is:

Could someone explain to me how I can go about implementing event handling in F#?  I cannot find anything on google that is not for GUI applications.  How can I turn the example C# code above into something in F#?

Any explanation of downvotes would also be appreciated, my original question was partly answered by some people and I discovered some answers for myself but it has not been fully answered, the question merely evolved into something slightly different.

Comment: use imap idle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE for real time notifications. If you don't want to implement IMAP yourself consider MailSystem.NET

Comment: What did you try, and where did you stumble?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet (well, I'm going to look at implementing the service in the way mentioned in the link I posted now).  FYI I am using AENet mail which I think has some support for IMAP Idle although I have absolutely no idea how to use this.  Has anyone done this?

Comment: I am looking into [this](http://smiley22.github.com/S22.Imap/Documentation/) now, looks quite promising although I now need to look at how I use Events in F#!

Comment: Any explanation of the downvote would be appreciated as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the API you're using makes this extremely easy. You don't need to implement your own polling since the IMAP client provides the `NewMessage` event. The example you referenced (*EDIT 2*) is a console app, so the call to `Thread.Sleep` prevents it from exiting immediately. This isn't an issue in a Windows service. The process will be kept alive by the service manager. The following code should provide a working foundation for your service.

```ml
open S22.Imap

type ImapService() =
  inherit System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase()

  let mutable client = null

  override __.OnStart(_) = 
    client <- new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993,
      "username", "password", AuthMethod.Login, true)
    client.NewMessage.Add(fun args ->
      let msg = client.GetMessage(args.MessageUID, FetchOptions.HeadersOnly)
      //do something with msg
      ()
    )

  override __.OnStop() = 
    client.Dispose()
```

Comment: That's awesome, exactly what I'm looking for.  Just one more question, if I run this as a console app how can I stop the application cleanly?

Comment: You could insert a call to `Console.Read()` followed by `client.Dispose()` before the `main` method returns.